# Как лучше всего парсить этот API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Вот API Spotify, у них ссылки с поиском трека формируются таким образом:

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Where+are+U&type=track&limit=1
```

Так вот, как лучше всего выводить эту песню на сайт при помощи JS? Что посоветуете? Или возможно есть готовое решение? Или помогите пожалуйста с этим кодом :)

Comment: эм, это обычный `json`, делаете `JSON.parse(str)` и вы уже имеете весь этот объект, а дальше что напишите, то и будет выводиться

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста пример кода, именно в данном случае, спасибо.

Comment: Эм, `$.ajax('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Where+are+U&type=track&limit=1').then(function (data) {console.log(data);})`, `data` внутри это объект, возвращаемый с нужного вам сервера

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: `then` на `success` поменяйте

Comment: Ок, тут захостил пример, http://music.mega-mind.info/ и как вывести в консоль допустим items -> preview_url

Comment: Вы с javascript работали когда нибудь? Если нет, то я попрошу вас пойти и почитать, как работать с объектами. Там все достаточно просто

Comment: Работал, просто мне было бы гараздо удобнее, если бы вы дали мне пример именно в данном случае, спасибо за то что помогаете ;)

Comment: Понятное дело, что было бы удобнее чтобы я дал вам готовый ответ, но тогда вы не научитесь думать, т.к. ответ на ваш последний вопрос вы сами и написали. Там где вы написали про хост сервер. Просто синтаксически немного иначе будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получаете json и выводите его как хотите, главное понять структуру, где альбомы, где фотки, где артисты.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>titile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Where+are+U&type=track&limit=1',
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function(resp) {

          //ручной вывод чего-то на страницу
          $('div.man').append('<img src=' + resp.tracks.items[0].album.images[2].url + '>')
            .append('<div><b><u>' + resp.tracks.items[0].album.name + '</u></b></div>');

          $(resp.tracks.items[0].artists).each(function(index, el) {
            $('div.man').append('<div>' + resp.tracks.items[0].artists[index].name + '</div>');
          });

          //вывод всего json
          $('div.div').text(JSON.stringify(resp));
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="man"></div>
  <hr>
  <div class="div">загрузка сюда...</div>
</body>

</html>
```